# Asp MVC 2: Typed Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, viewdata, strongly-typed-view, editorfor

(I reference [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/07/01/using-viewmodel-information-in-an-asp-net-mvc-2-editor-or-display-template.aspx) in this text)

I want to use the Html.EditorFor (or Html.Editor) helpers.

If a UserControl needs **additional data** it is passed via

`...EditorFor(model => model.Album, new { Artists = Model.Artists, ... })`

In the UserControl it's accessed via **ViewData[*stringKey*]**, ie

`... new SelectList(ViewData["Artists"] as IEnumerable, ...`

To me this smells a little fishy as I would **prefer a strongly typed ViewModel** which ensures that specific data is available.

I'm now a little bit stuck as I don't know wheater there's a "typed way" to find or I should accept this way as-is.

How did you solve this issue? Any help appreciated!

Lg
warappa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably change my view model so that I don't need to pass this additional information. You could make for example an album has a collection of artists. Now all tha you will have to do is:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Album) %>
```

And in your editor template:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedArtist, new SelectList(Model.Artists)) %>
```

Comment: I think ´Album´ shouldn't be concerned with something like "what are all artists we know?"

But another question: Is it bad practice to reference a repository from an editor template directly?

Comment: @Warappa, yes it is very bad to reference a repository from a view. The view is there to only show data passed from the controller. It's the controller that should manipulate the repository.

Comment: OK, I see. If I want to make it typed do I have to make a UserControl not for Type "Album" but for **"AlbumEditorViewModel"** (and would this be the best way)?

Comment: @Warappa, absolutely, using a view model which is specifically tailored to a given view is the best approach.

Comment: And if there's another complex object nested which also needs to be editable (ie. SelectedArtist) the outer viewmodel would contain a property which is of the inner viewmodel-type? Right? (edit) ... and it's OK that a EditorTemplate calls another EditorTemplate?